# Web.config change in asp.net web form in different build in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have found a link which describe web.config transformation
[Link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859)

But i happens only when i  publish the web application.

**Is it possible to load it when ever i build my web application????**.

As an example, whenever i build in Debug  mode i want to use `Web.Debug.config` 
and use release build to force `Web.Release.config` configuration for my aplication.

Comment: Is it possible? Well, that's how it is intended to work, why isn't it working like that for you?

Comment: It should be working for you. You could have something corrupted in your Visual Studio install. Do you mind zipping up your project and sharing it, IFF it's nothing major and seeing if it broken for others as well?

Comment: It works when published to file system by Build->Publish myApp->Published to local file system. But not when i build my application to Debug/Release mode